# Having trouble reading and writing unicode/non-ascii characters to file in python

Tags: python, unicode, filenames

I have a directory structure that contains many directories with non-ascii characters, mostly sanskrit. I am working on indexing these directories/files in a script, but can't figure out how best to handle these instances. This is my process:

- hash all files, recursively, write the path, filename, and hash of each to a .tsv file.
- go through this file, sorting each line by whether a duplicate of the hash exists. results in a dictionary with this form: `{'path': columns[0], 'filename': columns[1], 'status': True}`, where status determines whether an action is later taken on the file.
- go through this dictionary, move duplicates out of their original location and into an offset-root path (./duplicates rather than ./, for instance).
- write to a file for each move a command to run that will reverse the move, if necessary (just `mv a b`); this isn't important, but thought I'd include it.

Below is some sample data and what I've written so far:

Sample generated tsv (path/name/hash):

```
./Personal Research/Ramnad 9"14"10  DSC_0004.JPG    850cd9dcb0075febd4c0dcd549dd7860        
./Personal Research/Ramnad 9"14"10  DSC_0010.JPG    9db2219fc4c9423016fb9e295452f1ad        
./Personal Research/Ramnad 9"14"10  DSC_0006.JPG    ef7d13b88bbaabc029390bcef1319bb1
```

The `"` is actually unicode:

> **Block:**    Private Use Area
>   **Unicode:**      U+F019
>   **UTF-8:**    0xEF 0x80 0x99
>   **JavaScript:**   0xF019

Code:
writing the above to file (fulltsv):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SRC_DIR, topdown=True):
        files[:] = [f for f in files if any(ext in f for ext in EXT_LIST) if not f.startswith('.')]
        for file in files:
            with open(os.path.join(root,file),'r') as f:
                with open(SAVE_DIR+re.sub(r'\W+', '', os.path.basename(root).lower())+'.tsv', 'a') as fout:
                    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t', quotechar='\"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                    checksums = []
                    with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'rb') as _file:
                        checksums.append([root, file, hashlib.md5(_file.read()).hexdigest()])
                        writer.writerows(checksums)
```

reading from that file:

```
#       generate list of all tsv
for (dir, subs, files) in os.walk(ROOT):
    #   remove the new-root from the search
    subs = [s for s in subs if NROOT not in s]
    for f in files:
        fpath = os.path.join(dir,f)
        if ".tsv" in fpath:
            TSVLIST.append(fpath)

#       open/append all TSV content to a single new TSV
with open(FULL,'w') as wfd:
    for f in TSVLIST:
        with open(f,'r') as fd:
            wfd.write(fd.read())
            lines = sum(1 for line in f)

#   add all entries to a dictionary keyed to their hash
entrydict = {}

ec = 0
with open(FULL, 'r') as fulltsv:
    for line in fulltsv:
        columns = line.strip().split('\t')
        if not columns[2].startswith('.'):
            if columns[2] not in entrydict.keys():
                entrydict[str(columns[2])] = []

            entrydict[str(columns[2])].append({'path': columns[0], 'filename': columns[1], 'status': True})
            if len(entrydict[str(columns[2])]) > 1:
                ec += 1

ed = {k:v for k,v in entrydict.items() if len(v)>=2}
```

moving duplicates:

```
 for e in f:
            if len(f)-mvcnt > 1:
                if e['status'] is True:
                    p = e['path']    #   path
                    n = e['filename']   #   name
                    n0,n0ext = os.path.splitext(n)
                    n1 = n

                    #   directory structure for new file
                    FROOT = p.replace(p.split('/')[0],NROOT,1)
n1 = n

                    rebk = 'mv {0}/{1} {2}/{3}'.format(FROOT,n,p,n)
                    shutil.move('{0}/{1}'.format(p,n),'{0}/{1}'.format(FROOT,n))
                    dupelist.write('{0} #{1}\n'.format(rebk,str(h)))
                    mvcnt += 1
```

Errors I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 550, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '"./Personal Research/Ramnad 9""14""10"/DSC_0003.NEF' -> './duplicateRoot/Personal Research/Ramnad 9""14""10"/DSC_0003.NEF'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dCompare.py", line 164, in <module>
    shutil.move('{0}/{1}'.format(p,n),'{0}/{1}'.format(FROOT,n))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 564, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 263, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '"./Personal Research/Ramnad 9""14""10"/DSC_0003.NEF'
```

Obviously the has to do with how I'm handling unicode characters, but I've never worked with this before and am not sure at which point/how I should be handling the filenames. Working on ubuntu 10 under windows subsystem for linux, python 3.

Comment: It's not directly related to the issue, but it might be worth using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Comment: I don't see `with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:` in the source code listings you have provided.  How do you build the string `src`?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn that is from shutil.py

Comment: @AMC I will, but I am interested in understanding the reasoning for the problems I'm having rather than just throwing modules at it.

Answer (score 0):

The one problem I see when I read over the stack-trace is that the Unicode characters are wrong (they're not there) given OP's sample TSV:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '"./Personal Research/Ramnad 9""14""10"/DSC_0003.NEF' -> './duplicateRoot/Personal Research/Ramnad 9""14""10"/DSC_0003.NEF'
```

There's some quote escaping in the source and destination paths that I believe shouldn't be there, the extra and double double-quotes, looks like the path was broken up and concatenated again (or something):

`'"./Personal Research/Ramnad 9""14""10"/DSC_0003.NEF'`

I attempted to recreate OP's error, but couldn't.  But, when I was working through the sample below, I originally got a `FileNotFoundError` (because I was missing the destination folders, hence `os.makedirs()` in my sample), but the path was correctly encoded:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'foo/Personal Research/Ramnad 9\uf01914\uf01910/DSC_0006.JPG'`

All I can offer is speculation that the encoding is messed up either in the TSV file, or in `entrydict`.  OP, have you inspected that file or dict in the interpreter and verified you're seeing `\uf019` in the paths where you expect?  Maybe something like the following to make sure those codepoints are present:

```
>>> print(path.encode('unicode_escape'))
b'./Personal Research/Ramnad 9\\uf01914\\uf01910'
>>> # or, look for 61465
>>> [ord(char) for char in path]
[46, 47, 80, 101, 114, 115, 111, 110, 97, 108, 32, 82, 101, 
115, 101, 97, 114, 99, 104, 47, 82, 97, 109, 110, 97, 100, 
32, 57, 61465, 49, 52, 61465, 49, 48]
```

Here is my attempt, it might help...

I created a sample TSV file and the corresponding directory structure:

```
>>> p='./Personal Research/Ramnad 9\uf01914\uf01910'
>>> os.makedirs(p)
>>> checksums=[[p, 'DSC_0006.JPG', 'hash']]
>>> with open('full.tsv', 'a') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t', quotechar='\"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerows(checksums)
```

and touched the file in the shell:

```
$ touch Personal\ Research/Ramnad\ 91410/DSC_0006.JPG
```

Inspected `full.tsv` to make sure it was correctly written to:

```
$cat full.tsv
./Personal Research/Ramnad 91410  DSC_0006.JPG    hash
```

The empty-blocks are the properly utf-8-encoded codepoint based on the Unicode description of `"` that OP included.

Ran `hexdump -C full.tsv` to ensure the utf-8 encoding (look for 2 sets of `ef 80 99`):

```
00000010  72 63 68 2f 52 61 6d 6e  61 64 20 39 ef 80 99 31  |rch/Ramnad 9...1|
00000020  34 ef 80 99 31 30 09 44  53 43 5f 30 30 30 36 2e  |4...10.DSC_0006.|
```

I then ran

```
>>> entrydict = {}

>>> ec = 0
>>> with open('full.tsv', 'r') as fulltsv:
    for line in fulltsv:
        columns = line.strip().split('\t')
        if not columns[2].startswith('.'):
            if columns[2] not in entrydict.keys():
                entrydict[str(columns[2])] = []

            entrydict[str(columns[2])].append({'path': columns[0], 'filename': columns[1], 'status': True})
            if len(entrydict[str(columns[2])]) > 1:
                ec += 1

>>> entrydict
{'hash': [{'path': './Personal Research/Ramnad 9\uf01914\uf01910', 'filename': 'DSC_0006.JPG', 'status': True}]}`
```

And finally:

```
>>> e = entrydict['hash'][0]
>>> e
{'path': './Personal Research/Ramnad 9\uf01914\uf01910', 'filename': 'DSC_0006.JPG', 'status': True}
>>> NROOT='foo'
>>> if e['status'] is True:
    p = e['path']    #   path
    n = e['filename']   #   name
    n0,n0ext = os.path.splitext(n)
    n1 = n

    #   directory structure for new file
    FROOT = p.replace(p.split('/')[0],NROOT,1)


    rebk = 'mv {0}/{1} {2}/{3}'.format(FROOT,n,p,n)
    print(rebk)
    src='{0}/{1}'.format(p,n)
    dst='{0}/{1}'.format(FROOT,n)
    os.makedirs(FROOT)
    shutil.move(src,dst)
```

and it worked.  Bummer.

Comment: This is basically identical to what I have. I'm going through it all again and will check what I have against your results, but I did check and the directory appears to be encoded correctly. If I'm screwing it up I think it's when I re-read the TSVs; whether it's when they're aggregated or not I'm not sure, but that's my next focus. Thanks a ton for all your work, that was great to read.